# How to decide an object behavior through the web.config?

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns, web-config

I want to be able to define in my web.config the type of connexion my object will use to get data (variable) (from an xml or from a databases).

I though about using a Strategie Pattern, but I'm somewhat stuck by the need to write somewhere the name of the class, which I do not want.

Any suggestions?

### Additionnal info

I have the interface **IContext**. 
It's implemented in **ContextXML** and **ContextDB**.

I have the class **Context** which has a **IContext** member (called **_context**).

The **Context** class reads (through **ContextConfiguration**) *app.config*.

I want **_context** to be able to be a **ContextXML** or a **ContextDB**... or a **ContextJSon** or any other new class that would implements **IContext**.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about creating a `ContextManager` class and employing "configuration by convention"?

What I would do, is add a member `getName` to your `IContext` interface - this just returns a nice human-readable string for each implementation - as simple as **"ContextXML"** for your `ContextXML` class.

When your `ContextManager` (probably a Singleton, BTW) starts up, it scans a known directory for `IContext` implementations, instantiating them by reflection (or some other mechanism, I'm not familiar with VB.Net but I'm sure there's a way), and placing them in a collection.

Now when you are building up `Context` objects, you can ask your `ContextManager` for a suitable `IContext` - either explicitly [e.g. `getIContextByName("ContextDB")`] or with a simpler method that just returns whatever has been configured by some other mechanism - i.e. a suite of methods something like this:

- `getPossibleIContextImplementationNames()`
- `setCurrentIContextImplementation({name})`
- `getCurrentIContext()`

Just as an aside, are you stuck with that naming? Because having a `Context` object that *uses* an `IContext` seems a little unusual. If your `IContext` implementations are actually used to retrieve data from somewhere, why not call the interface `IDAO` or `IDataAccessor`?